# How to query custom post type testimonials and generate Ul list and create JS Slider

Tags: php, wordpress

I had created custom testimonial by using post type. I want to create a JS testimonials slider on home page . I dont have an idea how to do it .. please help me

```
add_action( 'init', 'testimonials_post_type' );
function testimonials_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Testimonials',
        'singular_name' => 'Testimonial',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Testimonial',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Testimonial',
        'new_item' => 'New Testimonial',
        'view_item' => 'View Testimonial',
        'search_items' => 'Search Testimonials',
        'not_found' =>  'No Testimonials found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Testimonials in the trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
    );

    register_post_type( 'testimonials', array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 10,
        'supports' => array( 'editor' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'testimonials_meta_boxes', // Callback function for custom metaboxes
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Do you want create it by own, otherwise many plugins are there in wordpress.org to help you on this.

Comment: I had taken some help from various tutorials. now testimonials posts are getting created and saved in the DB... Just want to query in ul list and create a slideshow with it

Comment: You can use this plugin which is creating Post Type like you and Shortcode and easy to use. https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-testimonial-slider-and-grid/

Comment: Thank you for the plugin.. but I vl try to make it without plugin... can u help me with that?

Comment: You can get the code from the plugin too.